# How to resolve ERROR in ./0.53b2f8ac.js from Terser Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, github-actions

Getting above error in npm run build on github workflow, However the same running in local without any issues. I'm using react 18 running on node 20.10.0

I've added  "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack --config ./config/webpack/webpack.prod.js --history-api-fallback" in package.json. It worked in local and created the build but i got above error while running in github workflow